# universal-cookie returning undefined for JWT cookie in useCheckToken hook

Tags: node.js, react-hooks

I've encountered an issue with the universal-cookie library in my React application. Specifically, when using the useCheckToken hook to retrieve a JWT cookie, the value returned by cookies.get("jwt") is consistently undefined, even though I can confirm that the cookie is being set.

Here's the relevant code snippet from my useCheckToken hook:

```
// useCheckToken.jsx
const { VITE_API_SERVER } = import.meta.env;
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();


export const useCheckToken = async function () {
  try {
    const token = cookies.get("jwt");
    console.log("token", token);

    if (!token) return false;

    const checkToken = await fetch(`${VITE_API_SERVER}/checkToken`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });

    console.log("response", checkToken);
    const data = await checkToken.json();

    if (data.error) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

I'm setting the cookies in my backend when a user logs in using the following code:

```
const login_user_post = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.login(email, password);
    const token = createToken(user._id);
    res.cookie('jwt', token, { httpOnly: true, secure: true, maxAge: maxAge * 1000 });
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'User logged in successfully', user: user._id, token });
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = handleErrors(err);
    res.status(401).json({ errors });
  }
};
```

I've confirmed that the cookie is being set in the backend, but the token variable in the hook is always undefined. I'm reaching out to the community for help in understanding why this might be happening and how I can resolve the issue.

**Additional Information:**

- I'm using the universal-cookie library to manage cookies in my React application.
- The backend server is correctly setting the JWT cookie, and I can see it in the browser's developer tools.
- The issue occurs specifically when trying to retrieve the cookie value in the useCheckToken hook.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

I initially used the js-cookie library, but it also returned undefined all the time, I thought the library was faulty, then some of my friends recommended using universal-cookie which I did, but still, I got the same error. each time I tried retrieving the cookie value of "jwt" it kept returning undefined.

Comment: Do you know https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies?